# How can I properly move the generated NSManagedObject subclasses into the project?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I just generated some `NSManagedObject` subclasses and Xcode adds them in a very weird position:

[image]

The files in the red frame (not hand-drawn) are the generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses. As you can see, they are not in my target "Math Toolbox", which files are in the green frame.

Therefore, the `NSManagedObject` subclasses are not being compiled when I build the app.

So I try to drag them into the target, and the result looks so horrible:

[image]

There are two sets of these files!

I thought the files outside the target can be deleted. So I deleted it but then the files in the target turned red and has become inaccessible!

This is just a mess!

How can I move the files into the target and also leave no files outside the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one has always harassed me!

Simple Steps to follow.
Create the subclass the way you did, it will create the one in red box.

**When you create, ensure you put them in a new proper folder -->**

[image]

**Next, delete those in the red box, but do a remove reference -->**

[image]

**Next, add those back, before that, create  a new group, or select the group where you want them to be -->**

[image]

[image]

**And select those files -->**

[image]

***The final output -->***

[image]